# Windows TabControl with Appearance=Buttons, getting wide margins on the right

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm creating a Windows C#/.NET app, and I'm trying to use a TabControl with the Appearance set to Buttons. I want the tabs to have images only, no text. However, I'm getting a bunch of extra padding on the right side of each button, which I'd like to get rid of:

[image]
I am able to reduce the right margin by reducing the font size to 1, but it's still a few pixels wider than the left side, and it seems a bit kludgy. Is there a better way?

Comment: Microsoft barely made an effort to make that work.  DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed might be the only way to make it work with the ItemSize set and the SizeMode set to Fixed.

Comment: The image is simply left-aligned and the tab width can't be too small so you'll end up with extra space to the right of the image.  Consider a more appropriate (wider) image or ownerdraw.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public frmForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.Buttons;
     tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
     tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);
}

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Load the image
    Image img = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}\\{1}.jpg",Application.StartupPath,tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Name));
    //Resize image
    img = new Bitmap(img, e.Bounds.Size);
    //Draw on Tab Button
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.Bounds.Location);
}
```

[image]